# Is this the way to scan multiple inputs using scanner

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class servlt {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in1.nextInt();
        int n=0, m=0;
        String input[] = new String[t];
        for ( int i = 0; i<t; i++){
            input[i] = in1.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

there is nothing stored in `input[0]`. May I know why?

Comment: Can you define "multiple inputs"?

Comment: input can be given as any number of lines. first input shows how many inputs are coming next so if i give 3 as first input it means I'm going to give 3 more inputs next

Comment: Then read data using `nextLine` and split it using `\\s+`. First token will be number of input values, the following tokens will be the actual input values.

Answer (score 2):

change your code to

```
int t = in1.nextInt();
in1.nextLine();
```

it needs to swallow up the linefeed

Answer (score 0):

nextInt() wont consume the \n (new line), then nextLine will consume \n character from the number of lines ( left by nextInt ). You can use Integer.parseInt(in1.nextLine()) or and another in1.nextLine() right after you nextInt(), to consume the \n char.

**Trace of your code**

```
    Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in1.nextInt(); // read a number (let say 3)
    int n=0, m=0;
    String input[] = new String[t];
    for ( int i = 0; i<t; i++){
        input[i] = in1.nextLine(); // the first time nextLine will read the \n char
    // The second time an 1 ( for example )
    // And the third time a 2 ( for example )\
    }

    // Finally you will have an array like this
    // input[0] = "\n"
    // input[0] = "1"
    // input[0] = "2"
```

**FIX**

```
  Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = Integer.parseInt(in1.nextLine());

    int n=0, m=0;
    String input[] = new String[t];
    for ( int i = 0; i<t; i++){
        input[i] = in1.nextLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is solution, just change `input[i] = in1.nextLine();` to `input[i] = in1.next();` and it's working, i test it in my locally.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class servlt {

        public static void main (String args[]){
            Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter total number you want to store:: ");
            int t = in1.nextInt();
            int n=0, m=0;
            String input[] = new String[t];
            for ( int i = 0; i<t; i++){
                System.out.println("enter "+i+"th number :");
                input[i] = in1.next();
            }
            for (int j=0;j<t;j++)
            {
                System.out.println("input["+j+"] value is : "+input[j]);
            }
}
}
```